# bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module in React native UI Kitten

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./style/styleConsumer.component` from `node_modules\@ui-kitten\components\theme\index.js`:

Getting this error after upgrading Ui Kitten from **4.3.1** to **4.4.0**

The detailed log is:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./style/styleConsumer.component` from `node_modules\@ui-kitten\components\theme\index.js`:

None of these files exist:   * node_modules\@ui-kitten\components\theme\style\styleConsumer.component(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
* node_modules\@ui-kitten\components\theme\style\styleConsumer.component\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (d:\HotelAppNoExpo\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8eZc.png)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start your app with [clearing cache](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/650#issuecomment-545358903)